# EMR 6.7 configuration in EMR 6.9 gives error Classification 'spark-log4j' is not valid for parent classification 'null'

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, amazon-emr

I was using emr 6.7 with the software configuration:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties": {
      "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark-log4j",
    "Properties": {
      "log4j.rootCategory": "ERROR, console"
    }
  }
]
```

but for some reason when I shifted to emr 6.9.

The was website started throwing error

> Classification 'spark-log4j' is not valid for parent classification
> 'null'.

[image]

If I remove this spark-log4j then it works but starts giving unnecessary INFO and DEBUG logs

How can I configure spark-log4j in EMR 6.9?

Answer (score 7):

Change the classification to 'spark-log4j2' from 'spark-log4j' in your configuration as newer EMR versions use log4j2 for spark now.
Here is the documentation for valid classifications: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-690-release.html#emr-690-class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As [@gyökkettő](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20541941/gy%C3%B6kkett%C5%91) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186476/11692715)

> Change the classification to 'spark-log4j2' from 'spark-log4j'

This is the final configuration that worked for me for EMR 6.9

```json
[
  {
    "classification": "spark",
    "properties": {
      "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "classification": "spark-log4j2",
    "properties": {
      "rootLogger.level": "error"
    }
  }
]
```

replace
`"Classification": "spark-log4j",` with `"classification": "spark-log4j2"`

and

`"log4j.rootCategory": "ERROR, console"` with `"rootLogger.level": "error"`